# Adjusting the space between elements set by justify-content space-between

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there any way to reduce the space in `justify-content:space-between`?

There is too much space between elements.

`space-around` is no solution either, so I was wondering if maybe I can for example say that I want the space to be 10px for instance.

Here is an example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.child:first-child {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <p>The thing you want fixed to the bottom of the container.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o3r40keu/5/

There is too much space between divs. I would like it to be smaller.

Comment: Can you edit your post and provide some HTML & CSS code? It's hard to give help here without knowing the context.

Comment: @caymanroe https://jsfiddle.net/o3r40keu/5/ there is too much blank space between divs. I would like it to be smaller

Comment: Add minus margins to preferred elements

Comment: Isn't that the point of `space-between`? You have an element of a certain size, and you want to place the children in such a way that the spacing between them is all equal. With two children, the only way that can happen is to leave all of the space in between the two. Either shrink the size of the parent, or maybe you don't want justification anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The extra space you are seeing is being caused by that min-height property. Try changing it to something lower than 250px. For example:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 50px;       /*Changing from 250px -> 50px*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give preferred element position of relative, and align it using minus top property.
https://jsfiddle.net/o3r40keu/24

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child:first-child {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.child:last-child {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

literal solution: increase the size of the flex items.

but if those just contain text - like in your example - there's no alternative: space-between places the outmost items at the outmost position, the space between them is just the result of the container size minus the sizes of the flex items.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;  //change space-between to flex-start
  min-height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child:first-child {
  padding-bottom: 0px;  //adapt padding-bottom if you want
}
```